# Updating EJS Include Methodology

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I should preface this by saying that I have never contributed to open source, and am very excited to start with ejs.

So I decided it was high time to update EJS's include methodology.

I decided to start by first adding the ability to include files from a relative or a absolute path, but I'm a little stuck because I am unsure how to access the app engine's (in this case express's) view root (in case it is different from "/views/"

So far, I have edited the resolveInclude function near line 280 in node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js and added 2 other functions. One that splits the path at the view root, which is currently only static, at "/views/"... obviously this needs to be dynamic, and set to the app engine's view root. Hence, my predicament...

```
/**
 * Resolve include `name` relative to `filename`.
 *
 * @param {String} name
 * @param {String} filename
 * @return {String}
 * @api private
 */
function resolveInclude(name, filename) {
    var path;
    if (0 == name.trim().indexOf('./')) path = dirname(filename);
    else path = resolveFromViewsRoot(dirname(filename), '/views/');
    path = join(path, name);
    return addExtension(path);
}
/**
 * Resolve include `name` relative to `root in '/views/ folder'`.
 *
 * @param {String} path
 * @param {String} root
 * @return {String}
 * @api private
 */
function resolveFromViewsRoot(path, root) {
    path = path.split(root);
    var nuPath = path.shift();
    nuPath = nuPath + root;
    return nuPath;
}
/**
 * Add ejs extension to file name
 *
 * @param {String} path
 * @return {String}
 * @api private
 */
function addExtension(path) {
    if (!extname(path)) return path + '.ejs';
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is needed because I am having trouble with EJS include right now, a really slippery problem. I am having trouble with EJS on the front-end. 'filename option is required' and 'dirname is not a function'. Frankly, I don't think a library like EJS should be coded for both the front-end and back-end, but that would dash the isomorphic dream wouldn't it. EJS should have a back-end and front-end version.